# javascript error 'cannot read property of undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The javascript, html and css work in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/24M3n/1/)
but when entered into an html file like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var target = $(".mypara").offset().top;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
                    alert("made it!");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    }
            }, 250);
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
            background-color: linen;
            height: 1000px;
            }
            p {
             color: blue;
              margin-top: 500px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
     <p class="mypara">asdfasdfasf</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

chrome console gives this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(anonymous function) @ index - Copy.html:8

This error refers to line 8:

```
var target = $(".mypara").offset().top;
```

Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    // code here
});
```

You're trying to access an element in the DOM before it exists so when your trying to access the class the item doesnt exist yet. Or move your script below the elements in the html

Works in fiddle cause thet wrap you're code depending on your setting which defaults to domready I believe

Comment: Happens to all of us. Sometimes all it takes is a 2nd set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">

        <style>
            body {
                background-color: linen;
                height: 1000px;
            }
            p {
                color: blue;
                margin-top: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="mypara">asdfasdfasf</p>
        <p class="mypara">Include js files to be at the bottom so that it would be the one to be loaded accordingly</p>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // if document is ready then
            // its the only time to execute
            // process withing the block
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var target = $(".mypara").offset().top;
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
                        alert("made it!");
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 250);
            });

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```